# What to use to soundproof the ceiling from footsteps and falling objects?

Tags: sound-proofing

I would like to soundproof my 60 foot living room from the noises of the upper floor, in particular the noises of footsteps (there is a 5-year-old girl running much time of the day) and falling objects / furniture moving (therefore low frequencies); voices or television I hear them less or in any case, they bother me less.
I would like to install a false ceiling (up to a maximum of 6-7-8 inch ) with a sound absorbing material. What do you recommend?

- Fiberglass ?
- Rock Wool ?
- Cork ?
- Other ?

Thank you

Comment: Got 6" or so for a drop ceiling?   They don't call 'em acoustic panels for nothing!

Comment: "60 foot living room"??? 60' tall? 60' long? In any case, that's a _HUGE_ room and a big part of the problem could simply be resonance in a space that huge.

Answer (score 1):

Lead would be the best but it is illegal to use for this. I think fiberglass will be the most economical solution although not the only one. One solution is to tell the people upstairs they won a carpet and if the agree have a thick pad installed under it. Not the most inexpensive but the easiest on you. In a few years the 5 year old will grow up and the noise will change.

Comment: Maybe the five year old growing up is part of the worry.

Answer (score 1):

I have added sound proofing to ceiling assemblies before.

If you want to dampen the sound of running from your ceiling you should plan to spend $50k+ and not expect perfect results - you'll still hear running.

If $50k+ is your budget then,

1. Blow in roxul insulation into the existing joist cavities ( make sure no knob and tube wiring ).
2. Hat track installed perpendicular to joists ( ~2" tall )
3. Sound isolation clips
4. Two layers of 5/8" thick drywall green glued together installed with seems perpendicular  (add another 1 1/4" )
5. Get the ceiling to wall joins caulked (no sound path)
6. Ensure you have no potlights.

I have lived in a house with kids above on 2" concrete 1" hardwood.  Ceiling assembly was just 5/8" drywall, nothing in the joist bays.

I have also lived in hardwood on 5/8" ply, joist bays roxul (safeNsound), hat track / sound isolation clips, 2 layers of drywall tapered seams with green glue.  The green glue detail was crap and not done by professionals and not according to how many tubes you should be using per 4x8 sheet.

I have also been in houses with just hardwood on empty joists and you can hear all the conversations.  You can hear people walking and where they walk.  I imagine if someone jumped off a bed onto the floor your ears would rupture.

The 2" concrete assembly was the quietest.  All assemblies you hear the kids running and if they jump off a bed onto the floor it sounds like a bomb went off.  The sound noises that you don't care about music / talking are quite muffled or close to completely blocked ( sound goes out windows and comes back in more than through floor assembly ).

I'd love to know how the professionally installed 5/8" double drywall with green glue and sound isolation clips and properly separated ceiling / walls performs.

Good luck !

Comment: Did someone say carpet? :). And if you want to take that further, tell the kid to wear socks.  And weigh down the furniture.  IDK why people move furniture so much in your house, but if it weighs 300 pounds they might decide to do something else.

Comment: Yeah carpet is the most effective solution!  With the floor assembly details kid running is tolerable without carpet but expensive for those details and certainly not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I assisted treating the walls and ceiling of a noisy plant room, with offices above.

We used acoustic polyester batts, similar to thermal batts but very stiff.

Then just drywall (plasterboard).

It worked very well, when the door was closed.